# Register style in Project options -> Appearance for Delphi 12.0

Tags: delphi, delphi-12-athens, vcl-styles.-utils

I'm trying to create my own style in Delphi 12.0. I open the standard style editor Bitmap Style Designer. I open an existing style and save it under a new name. It was hoped that it would appear in Project options -> Appearance for further use in the IDE. But no. Looks like additional registration is required. How to do it?

I work under Windows 10 with Delphi 12.0

I tried to save the new style file as in standard Style directory
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\23.0\Redist\styles\vcl
as in
(Documents)\Embarcadero\Studio\23.0\Styles
by advise as here (https://theroadtodelphi.com/2011/09/01/exploring-delphi-xe2-vcl-styles-part-i/)

Also I changed Style Name and Author.

Answer (score 0):

You saved your modified/created style file in the wrong location. If you save your own creations/modifications in

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\23.0\Styles
```

then they will be available in your development project like Embarcadero provided style files.

The directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\23.0\Redist\styles\vcl` (and `...\styles\fmx`) is a repository of the standard style files that you can redistribute with your applications.

For additional information, see `VCL Styles Overview` in help.

---

**Note!** Of course, I also recommend to save the modified file under a different name, to retain the original file intact.

---

**Edit 6.3.2024**, sorry to here about your problem.

Just to be sure, I repeated the procedure and wrote down every step. Please note however, that I have version 22.0 whereas you have 23.0. There is a minor chance that something is different in your version, but I would not expect that. Just note that you need to apply your version where it matters for the paths.

**Here are my steps:**

-With the Bitmap Style Designer, choose "Open Style" and navigate to
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Styles\Luna.vsf

-the box after the "File name:" box says VCL Style / FMX Style Template(*.vsf)

-Hit 'Open' button

-Under 'Inspector' change names of
Author,
AuthorEMail,
AuthorURL,
Name (to e.g. MyLuna). I left AuthorEmail and AuthorURL empty.

-Leave MobilePlatform unticked (False)

-Save the style with a new name 'MyLuna.vsf', iow full path:
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Styles\MyLuna.vsf

-Close the style editor

-Return to the IDE

-Select Project - Options - Application - Appearance

-Scroll down the list to 'Various Authors'
and find the 'MyLuna' style listed

-Select it and hit the "Save" button. The name should logically imo be "Load". Anyway the style is now loaded into your project.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. I wrote I also saved my style file in 
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\23.0\Styles
and also I tried to save style in
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\23.0\Styles\vcl 
All attempts didn't lead to appear my style in Appearance

Comment: I also have Delphi 11.3. So I tried to reproduce all your steps, Tom, using same style (Luna) and same paths as in your message. Unfortunately, it couldn't decide issue on my system. I begin to think that problem in my PC.